# How do I apply the texture to my object?

Tags: texturing, uv

I just want to apply the bottom texture (assault rifle) to the side of the model I have currently.

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

The simplified way is to view the rifle from the side in the 3dview, then Press <kbd>U</kbd> and select Project From View, then position the uv's over the rifle picture. You would then need to cleanup the top and bottom faces.

You will find any UV unwrapping/mapping tutorial will help explain this more. You can [find plenty on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender%20uv%20unwrapping%20tutorial).